# Strange error when clicking in a web browser

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I have a problem with WebBrowser. I use it to navigate a website and everything is fine until I try to press this button:

```
<TD><INPUT  TYPE='BUTTON' class='BTN_FIXED' onClick="generaCSVWorkPlan()" VALUE="Generate CSV" TITLE="Generate CSV plan" ALT="Generate CSV"></TD>
```

I use the button directly, not from code, so it can't be a programming error, but I get this error which opens in a new window.
http://www.flyevo.it/tmp/cuperror.png (I am not authorized to post images directly)

Comment: Is this your website? If so we are going to need to see some backend code to determine what is happening. If not this is not the right place to ask this question.

Comment: No, it is not my website, otherwise I would know how to handle it, the problem, summarized, is that if I click from a browser everything works, if I make the same click from the WebBrowser (c #) component no. I don't understand where else I should pose the question.

Comment: Sorry, that is much harder to help. Their website is breaking for some reason. You might be able to hack around it but we won't be able to help without more information. For example seeing the actual page/function the button is calling. You should probably report this bug to them.

Comment: The problem is in the WebBrowser, if I use CefSharp everything is fine, but I can't use it because the CefSharp framework is 4.5.2 and I use Visual Studio 2010 with 4.0 framework. Is there a solution?